# How to count values in an csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to write a piece of code which takes information from a `.csv` file and counts the words and gives me a value of how many times it appeared. I have made the following code but it doesn't work correctly. It only does the first line. How can this be fixed?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

with open('verbatim.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    data=[]
    for line in csv_reader:
        for i in line:
            data.append(i)

    Counter(data)
    data_dict = dict(Counter(data))
    data_processed_dict = {'freq': data_dict}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_processed_dict)
    df['word'] = df.index
    df.to_csv('dataStatic.csv', index=False)
```

This is the data I'm trying to evaluate (there is over 400 lines like this):

```
1   ['investigate', 'wls', 'dash', 'pa', 'issue']
2   ['check', 'vehicle', 'non', 'start', 'assistance']
3   ['check', 'report', 'sound', 'vehicle', 'carry']
4   ['assistance', 'attend', 'vehicle', 'loss', 'electrical', 'system']
5   ['tcu', 'communicate', 'vehicle', 'unable', 'carry', 'campaign', 'n641']
6   ['eml', 'dash']
7   ['customer', 'state', 'bluetooth', 'carly', 'disconnect']
8   ['pdi', 'find', 'vehicle', 'start', 'perform', 'diagnostic', 'note', 'concern', '1', ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You are on the right track with:

```
for line in csv_reader:
    for i in line:
        data.append(i)
```

But you need to use a dictionary not a list so that it can count every occurrence:

```
with open('verbatim.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)   
    data = {} #notice the change here
    for line in csv_reader:
        for i in line:
            try:
                data[i] += 1
            except KeyError: 
                data[i] = 1
                print(f"{i} added to dictionary")
```

This will likely save time because you don't have to make the list with 2 for loops then try to use `Counter` after. It does it all at once.

**Example:**

Consider this test code:

```
fileLines = [
['investigate', 'wls', 'dash', 'pa', 'issue'],
['check', 'vehicle', 'non', 'start', 'assistance'],
['check', 'report', 'sound', 'vehicle', 'carry'],
['assistance', 'attend', 'vehicle', 'loss', 'electrical', 'system'],
['tcu', 'communicate', 'vehicle', 'unable', 'carry', 'campaign', 'n641'],
['eml', 'dash'],
['customer', 'state', 'bluetooth', 'carly', 'disconnect'],
['pdi', 'find', 'vehicle', 'start', 'perform', 'diagnostic', 'note', 'concern', '1', ]
]

data = {} #notice the change here
for line in fileLines:
    for i in line:
        try:
            data[i] += 1
        except KeyError: 
            data[i] = 1
            print(f"{i} added to dictionary")
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'investigate': 1, 
 'wls': 1, 
 'dash': 2, 
 'pa': 1, 
 'issue': 1, 
 'check': 2, 
 'vehicle': 5, 
 'non': 1, 
 'start': 2, 
 'assistance': 2, 
 'report': 1, 
 'sound': 1, 
 'carry': 2, 
 'attend': 1, 
 'loss': 1, 
 'electrical': 1, 
 'system': 1, 
 'tcu': 1, 
 'communicate': 1, 
 'unable': 1, 
 'campaign': 1, 
 'n641': 1, 
 'eml': 1, 
 'customer': 1, 
 'state': 1, 
 'bluetooth': 1, 
 'carly': 1, 
 'disconnect': 1, 
 'pdi': 1, 'find': 1, 
 'perform': 1, 
 'diagnostic': 1, 
 'note': 1, 
 'concern': 1, 
 '1': 1}
```

Also printed is:

```
investigate added to dictionary
wls added to dictionary
dash added to dictionary
pa added to dictionary
issue added to dictionary
check added to dictionary
vehicle added to dictionary
non added to dictionary
start added to dictionary
assistance added to dictionary
report added to dictionary
sound added to dictionary
carry added to dictionary
attend added to dictionary
loss added to dictionary
electrical added to dictionary
system added to dictionary
tcu added to dictionary
communicate added to dictionary
unable added to dictionary
campaign added to dictionary
n641 added to dictionary
eml added to dictionary
customer added to dictionary
state added to dictionary
bluetooth added to dictionary
carly added to dictionary
disconnect added to dictionary
pdi added to dictionary
find added to dictionary
perform added to dictionary
diagnostic added to dictionary
note added to dictionary
concern added to dictionary
1 added to dictionary
```